# where to put django-registration's activation_email.txt template

Tags: python, django, registration

As per the docs,it expects this file in a folder named 'registration' in templates directory.I tried that ,but I am getting a templateNotFound exception.

I have configured the registration template location like

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns=patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',....)

urlpatterns+=patterns('registration.views',
    url(r'^register/$','register',{'template_name':'myapp/registration_form.html'},name='myapp_register'),
    )
```

Is there some place I can configure the  location for activation_email.txt template ? When I submit the registration form ,the user is created in db ,but django searches all over python path for the activation_email.txt template

Why is it that all other templates are found with out any problem while this template is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your [TEMPLATE_DIRECTORIES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-template-dirs-setting) setting. The template paths are relative to any of the TEMPLATE_DIRECTORIES.

If `template_name` is `myapp/registration_form.html`, then you should **create a dir "myapp" in one of the TEMPLATE_DIRECTORIES**, and put `registration_form.html` in there.

To double check TEMPLATE_DIRECTORIES, run `manage.py shell` and in there `from django.conf import settings; print settings.TEMPLATE_DIRECTORIES`.